# Trigger Error that it's recursively calling itself

Tags: trigger

---

UPDATE
I put this on AfterUpdate instead of Before and it works!

Why?

---

The error seems self-explanatory enough, but I can't figure out why Salesforce says this is happening.

I have code to execute in "BeforeUpdate" that determines if a checkbox was just changed from unchecked to checked. If so, it runs some logic, including creating and OrderItem (with the triggered-Order's ID as its parent). I am not inserting this Order (which would make sense to cause this error), I am simply inserting the OrderItem which references the Order as its parent. It causes...

SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 8012a000000UTdz) is currently in trigger OrderTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []

That ID is in fact the ID of the Order which caused the trigger, but nowhere am I updating it - the line that causes this error, and mitigates it when commented out, is

insert newOrderItems, which contains an OrderItem with 
8012a000000UTdz as the parent.

Can somebody explain why this is happening, and maybe confirm if it's possible or not to create an OrderItem on this trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of rollup summary logic; when you create the line items, it tries to update the order's rollup summary values, but it's currently in the before DML trigger (not committed to the database), thus causing the error. As you've figured out, moving to an AfterUpdate trigger fixes it, because the record is no longer locked so the update can occur. This limit is in place because before triggers can modify the data before committing the record, so if it were allowed to update itself again, those values might be overwritten when it's recommitted from the other trigger further up the stack.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My confusion is because I'm never updating the Order in this logic, just inserting the OrderItem. Is your answer basically saying that the act of adding the OrderItem "updates" the Order in that the related list is now populated differently? Does that count as an Update? The way I see it, the list just pulls in orders dynamically by OrderId - is it actually an element that gets updated?

Comment: @NataliePaige You'll want to see [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm). There's a part during the transaction where rollup summary values are calculated, thus implicitly updating the order. Also note that this means you need to be careful how you write your triggers, because this can cause an infinite loop that will result in a LimitException.